# How to change background color of a label when double clicking it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem when trying to change a label's color in c# when double clicking the label when running the app. I have tried all kinds of stuff but I can't find a solution to it. I know it may be a newbie question for you, guys, but I would appreciate if you could help me. Thanks! Here is the WPF:

```
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="BestScore" Margin="0 0 30 0" Height="20" Grid.Column="0" Background="#CDCDCD"></TextBlock>
            <Button x:Name="PlayAgainButton" Click="PlayAgainButton_Click" Height="50" Grid.Column="1" Background="#F1EB5F" Content="Play Again"></Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="BestScoreFromFile" Margin="30 0 0 0" Height="20" Grid.Column="2" Background="#CDCDCD"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="Label1" Height="100" MouseDoubleClick="Label1_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 60 20 0" Background="Aqua"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="Label2" Height="100" MouseDoubleClick="Label2_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 60 0 0" Background="Aqua"></Label>
            <Label x:Name="Label3" Height="100" MouseDoubleClick="Label3_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20 60 0 0" Background="Aqua"></Label>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

And the C#:

```
 private void Label1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Background =Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a code sample, XAML and C#, showing what you tried. We don't need your whole application, just enough to understand what you're doing. Don't just show one line of C# code: Nobody can possibly guess where it is, or when it was called, or even *whether* it was called, or whether it's doing things to the right label, or indeed anything at all. [If we can't reproduce what happened on your computer, we can't help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're very likely to be downvoted for making so little effort to help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Label1.Background =Brushes.Red;
```